# Is it possible to extend Kotlin class without repeating the fields (parameters) in the constructor?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

Say for example we have a class and a derived class like this:

```
open class Base (
    val fieldA: String,
    val fieldB: String,
    val fieldC: String,
)

class Derived (
    fieldA: String,
    fieldB: String,
    fieldC: String,
    val fieldD: String,
): Base(fieldA, fieldB, fieldC)
```

Here `fieldA`, `fieldB`, `fieldC` are repeated in the derived class. Is it possible to reduce this boilerplate?

Having many arguments can be useful in some scenarios, for example working with entities in hibernate. The problem is that it can get very messy very quickly when adding more parameters and more derivation levels.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the variable in your base class as nullable or give them default value then there would be compulsion to pass them as parameter each and every time.

```
open class Base (
    val fieldA: String = "",
    val fieldB: String ="",
    val fieldC: String = ""
)
```